# nginx not serving the sitemap file

Tags: nginx

I am trying to server static sitemap file and my nginx configuration is:-

```
location /sitemap.xml/ {
    autoindex on;
    root /var/www/html;
}
```

so now when i try to do,

```
www.mysite.com/sitemap.xml
```

i get `404 not found` error.

so when i check the nginx error log file i see nginx is trying to search sitemap file on

```
/var/www/html/sitemap.xml/index.html
```

i don't understand why it is searching index.html file instead of sitemap.xml.

Comment: Try: `location /sitemap.xml`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of the `root` directive, full path is appended to the root including the location part, whereas in case of the `alias` directive, only the portion of the path NOT including the location part is appended to the alias.

So for:

```
 location = /sitemap.xml/ {
       autoindex on;
       root /var/www/html;
    }
```

nginx will create the final path to be:

`/var/www/html/sitemap.xml/*`

Assuming you don't have the `sitemap.xml` directory inside the `.../www/html/` directory, this will result in a 404 error.
If that's the case, you should use the `alias` directive. Where the location path is **dropped** before looking for the file at the said location.

try this:

```
location = /intern/ {
       autoindex on;
       alias /var/www/html/;  # <----- trailing slash is important here
    }
```

This should result in the path:

```
/var/www/html/*
```